# Red Black Tree - deletion

Tags: c++, red-black-tree

I've implemented delete function for RBT (basing on Cormen), it looks like it works but test for deletion + printing tree in preorder gives me wrong answer. I spent few hours looking what may be wrong but couldn't find anything...

Here's func to print tree in preorder:

```
void print_out(rbt_node *root, rbt_node *NIL)
{
    if(root != NIL)
    {
        printf("%d %s ", root->key, root->data.c_str());
        if(root->color == BLACK)
            printf("black ");
        else
            printf("red ");
        if(root->parent != NIL)
            printf("%d ",root->parent->key);
        else
            printf("- ");
        if(root->left != NIL)
            printf("%d ",root->left->key);
        else
            printf("- ");
        if(root->right != NIL)
            printf("%d ",root->right->key);
        else
            printf("- ");
        printf("\n");

        print_out(root->left, NIL);
        if(root->right != NIL)
        {
            print_out(root->right, NIL);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is rest of important stuff for deletion:

```
rbt_node *NIL = new rbt_node;
NIL->color = BLACK;
NIL->left = NIL->parent = NIL->right = NIL;

rbt_node *tree_minimum(rbt_node *node, rbt_node *NIL)
{
    while(node->left != NIL)
        node = node->left;

    return node;
}

rbt_node *tree_succesor(rbt_node *node, rbt_node *NIL)
{
    if(node->right != NIL)
        return tree_minimum(node->right, NIL);

    rbt_node *helper = node->parent;
    while(helper != NIL && node == helper->right)
    {
        node = helper;
        helper = helper->parent;
    }

    return helper;
}

void delete_fixup(rbt_node *&root, rbt_node *&target, rbt_node *NIL)
{
    rbt_node *helper = NIL;
    while(target != root && target->color == BLACK)
    {
        if(target == target->parent->left)
        {
            helper = target->parent->right;
            if(helper->color == RED)
            {
                helper->color = BLACK;
                target->parent->color = RED;
                left_rotate(root, target->parent, NIL);
                helper = target->parent->right;
            }
            if(helper->left->color == BLACK && helper->right->color == BLACK)
            {
                helper->color = RED;
                target = target->parent;
            }
            else if(helper->right->color== BLACK)
            {
                helper->left->color = BLACK;
                helper->color = RED;
                right_rotate(root, helper, NIL);
                helper = target->parent->right;
            }
            else
            {
                helper->color = target->parent->color;
                target->parent->color = BLACK;
                helper->right->color = BLACK;
                left_rotate(root, target->parent, NIL);
                target = root;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            helper = target->parent->left;
            if(helper->color == RED)
            {
                helper->color = BLACK;
                target->parent->color = RED;
                right_rotate(root, target->parent, NIL);
                helper = target->parent->left;
            }
            if(helper->right->color == BLACK && helper->left->color == BLACK)
            {
                helper->color = RED;
                target = target->parent;
            }
            else if(helper->left->color== BLACK)
            {
                helper->right->color = BLACK;
                helper->color = RED;
                left_rotate(root, helper, NIL);
                helper = target->parent->left;
            }
            else
            {
                helper->color = target->parent->color;
                target->parent->color = BLACK;
                helper->left->color = BLACK;
                right_rotate(root, target->parent, NIL);
                target = root;
            }
        }
    }

    target->color = BLACK;
}

void rbt_delete(rbt_node *&root, int key, rbt_node *NIL)
{
    rbt_node *victim = to_delete(root, key, NIL);
    if(victim != NIL)
    {
        rbt_node *help_one = NIL;
        rbt_node *help_two = NIL;
        if(victim->left == NIL || victim->right == NIL)
            help_one = victim;
        else
            help_one = tree_succesor(victim, NIL);

        if(help_one->left != NIL)
            help_two = help_one->left;
        else
            help_two = help_one->right;

        help_two->parent = help_one->parent;

        if(help_one->parent == NIL)
            root = help_two;
        else if(help_one == help_one->parent->left)
            help_one->parent->left = help_two;
        else
            help_two->parent->right = help_two;

        if(help_one != victim)
        {
            victim->key = help_one->key;
            victim->data = help_one->data;
        }

        if(help_one->color == BLACK)
            delete_fixup(root, help_two, NIL);
    }

    root->color = BLACK;
}
```

Comment: One day? You kidding me :D? Well you are wrong with it. Second of all, I provide source code (my source code), I just need help with catching bugs, that I might did and cannot find after spending few hours on checking .

Comment: What goes wrong? What is the data, what do you expect, what do you get?

Comment: http://www.speedyshare.com/files/28410102/tests.rar

That are tests + my output (it's kinda huge), problem appears after deleting third value and printing out tree (line 277 is wrong, after then few lines are wrong then it seems okay again...)

Answer (score 1):

At least IMO, your `print_out` isn't really working the way it should. The specific problem is that it's trying to (directly) print out data for child nodes.

When you're dealing with a binary tree (of any sort -- unbalanced, AVL, RB, etc.) traversal will normally look roughly like this:

```
void print_out(node *current_node) { 
    if current_node != NIL {
        show_data(current_node);

        print_out(current_node->left);
        print_out(current_node->right);
   }
}
```

As is, that's pre-order; post-order or inorder is just a matter of rearranging the `print_data` compared to the recursive calls to `print_out` (for post-order it comes after them, for inorder between them).

In particular, however, print_out should not have *anything* to do with the left or right sub-trees, other than by passing them as parameters in a recursive call. It also shouldn't normally check whether they're NIL/NULL either -- it should just make the recursive call, and let the `if (current_node != NIL)` handle in the recursive call deal with the possibility that we've hit a leaf node.

Call me lazy if you will, but that's about as much as I'm willing to examine without at least *some* guidance about what sort of problem I'm looking for, and at least as reasonable assurance that it's the right place to look. It would be helpful (for example) if you showed that you can insert a few nodes, and get the expected structure, then show *what* goes wrong when you delete a node. Is the node still there? Are other nodes getting lost? Are all the nodes right, but the balance is wrong? If so, what's going wrong with the balance?

Comment: Your method works exactly same as mine, that's not the issue, about guidance, I can just help with this I guess:
http://pastebin.com/GMaqGQsf
Nothing is lost, but balance seems wrong at this point. Later on there are more wrong lines, also nodes doesn't have expected color (but it's still valid tree). I could provide full source code if needed.